# Rails ActiveRecord search in entire JSON field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5 app I have a Postgres table with a JSON column.
I want to query for a term in all values, not only a specific one.

For example following JSON:

```
{
  "Cidade": "Rio de janeiro ",
  "Estado": "Rj "
}
```

I would like to use `Rio` or `de` or `Janeiro` or `Rj` to select the row in the table without specifying the key.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your table which contains json field is named `records` and your field name is `data` then your SQL query will be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM records 
JOIN json_each_text(records.data) r ON true
WHERE value LIKE '%Rio%' OR value LIKE '%de%' OR value LIKE '%Janeiro%' OR value LIKE '%Rj%'
```

Or with `Rails`

```rb
Record.joins('JOIN json_each_text(records.data) r ON true').where(
  'value LIKE ? OR value LIKE ? OR value LIKE ? OR value LIKE ?', "%Rio%", "%de%", "%Janeiro%", "%Rj%"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try

```
EX: colum => {
  "array"=>[ 
      "Cidade" => "Rio de janeiro ",
      "Estado" => "Rj "], 
}
```

```
value = params[:search_value]
Record.where("column ->> 'array' LIKE ?", "%value%")
```